# MySQL Query Slow with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I'm having a problem when I add in `ORDER BY date_last_access DESC` the whole query slows down to 3secs and without it's about 0.2secs, why is it running so slow and how can I change the query to run faster?

There are also indexes on all the tables and fields used.

Users: 1+ million records
Likes: 5+ million records (over 1 billion in production)

Tables will be growing really fast once in production.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    id,
    sid,
    first_name,
    date_birth,
    location,
    date_created,
    date_last_access,
    (3956 * 2 * ASIN(
        SQRT(
            POWER(
                SIN(
                    ({LAT} - latitude) * pi() / 180 / 2
                ),
                2
            ) + COS({LAT} * pi() / 180) * COS(latitude * pi() / 180) * POWER(
                SIN(
                    ({LON} - longitude) * pi() / 180 / 2
                ),
                2
            )
        )
    )) AS distance
FROM
    users
WHERE
    `id` != {UID} AND
    `gender` = {GEND} AND
    `date_birth` BETWEEN {DOB_MIN} AND {DOB_MAX} AND
    `status` = 'active' AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.judged_user = users.id AND likes.user_id = {UID}) = 0
HAVING distance <= {DIST}
ORDER BY date_last_access DESC
LIMIT {ROWS}
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
1   PRIMARY users   ref PRIMARY,Index_2,discovery,index_1   index_1 2   const   226184  Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

```
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  likes   eq_ref  PRIMARY,index_1,index_2 PRIMARY 16  const,hello.users.id    1   Using index
```

**INDEXES**

LIKES - `user_id`, `judged_user` - NORMAL - BTREE

USERS - `id`, `gender`, `date_birth`, `status`, `date_last_access` - NORMAL - BTREE

When I order by `id` instead of `date_last_access` it seems to run much faster, could it be cause date_last_access is a `datetime` format?

Comment: Do you have an index on `date_last_access `?

Comment: The *[query plan shows what](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html)*?

Comment: *There are also indexes on all the tables and fields used*: please show us exactly which indexes you have on the `users` table.

Comment: @Nick - Yeah i do

Comment: @GMB - Indexes

Likes - `user_id`, `judged_user`

Users - `id`, `gender`, `date_birth`, `status`, `date_last_access`

Comment: The query is getting a list of users around you that have not liked your profile

Comment: Try enabling the slow query log in MySQL.
This may help you identify the cause of the slow query.
I suspect you'll need to index some of field.
Have a look at - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: 1 PRIMARY users ref PRIMARY,Index_2,discovery,index_1 index_1 2 const 226184 Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort

Comment: recommend editing your question to include additional information.

Comment: 2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY likes eq_ref PRIMARY,index_1,index_2 PRIMARY 16 const,hello.users.id 1 Using index

Comment: A subquery over a million of records will perform slowly even if you have an index. You can simplify the subquery to check for one record instead of counting records, or to create a pivot table of users with no likes , avoiding a subquery

Comment: @F.Igor Any suggestion on how a subquery checking only one record would look (I'm an amateur at this lol) dont think the other options would work

Comment: `HAVING distance` obviously involves less typing than `WHERE (3952...`, but I suspect it's slower too.

Answer (score 1):

First try run a EXPLAIN of your query. This will show you what fields and operations are slowing your query. Then try to make joins with indexed columns and filter you resultset with more specific values.

Comment: Try use a LEFT join in place of subquery filtering a null or zero result of table "like"

Answer (score 1):

Simplyfying the subquery could be a better way to avoid extra processing time (COUNT):

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.judged_user = users.id AND likes.user_id = {UID}) = 0
```

could change to

```
(SELECT 1 FROM likes WHERE likes.judged_user = users.id AND likes.user_id = {UID} limit 1) IS NULL
```

Avoiding a subquery could be the best way to improve the performance of the query. You could check what options could be better for your case (an index for `likes.user_id` is required in this case)

```
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT distinct judged_user FROM likes WHERE likes.user_id = {UID}
) l ON l.judged_user=users.id
WHERE
    `id` != {UID} AND
    `gender` = {GEND} AND
    `date_birth` BETWEEN {DOB_MIN} AND {DOB_MAX} AND
    `status` = 'active' AND
    l.judged_user is NULL
```

Comment: So I've put the last option in and shaves off a little bit of time which is good, thank you.
Still got the problem where the `date_last_access` still slows it down dramatically tho. I've had this working fast with billions of records so still a lot of time before i have to worry again, its just when ordering it slows down. :/

Comment: Unfortunately, `id != {UID}` will not have a good performance (no index will be used) and ORDER BY (will scan all rows) so you can try to create an index over 'date_birth, status, gender' only (in this order, high cardinality to low cardinality) and let the engine do the rest (try removing the `!=` condition to see the difference)

Answer (score 0):

You should phrase the `FROM` clause as:

```
WHERE `id` <> {UID} AND
      `gender` = {GEND} AND
      `date_birth` BETWEEN {DOB_MIN} AND {DOB_MAX} AND
      `status` = 'active' AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM likes l WHERE l.judged_user = users.id AND l.user_id = {UID}) 
HAVING distance <= {DIST}
```

For this query, you can try two indexes:

- `LIKES(judged_user, user_id)`

  - `USERS(Gender, status, date_birth, id)`

Comment: That part works fine with over 1 billion records, the problem is the `ORDER BY` when I add that it slows it down.